# How cdef pyodbc rows during cythonizing?

Tags: python, cython, pyodbc

To cythonize the code below, how should I cdefine the row and rows?

```
conn_string = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};'
    r'DBQ=C:\Temp.mdb;')
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()
SQL = "SELECT number, address FROM data;"
rows = cursor.execute(SQL).fetchall()
cursor.close()
for row in rows:
    number = row[1]
```

Comment: Probably as nothing. Maybe as a `list` (if that's what they are). I doubt they're a type that's particularly useful to Cython though

Comment: Thank you @DavidW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DavidW mentioned in the comment, there is no need to define a type for row and rows, i.e., without any changes in the python code, the .c is generated successfully.